# 1 character only foreach loop result in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Hello i have this foreach loop that gives weird result , it displays only the first character form the db  record

```
<?php
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id,fp_thumb,title FROM media") or die(mysql_error());
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2) or die(Mysql_error());

foreach ($data2 as $val) {

  echo '<li><a href="media.php?id='.$val['id'].'"><img src="'.$val['fp_thumb'].'" alt="'.$val['title'].'" /></a></li>';
}
?>
```

and this is my DB structure

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for media
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `media` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `thumb` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `fp_thumb` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records 
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `media` VALUES ('1', '22', 'http://goeshere.com', '/images/slideshow/ctmbs.jpg', 'Test 1');
INSERT INTO `media` VALUES ('2', '2', 'http://goeshere1.com', '/images/slideshow/hitlex.jpg', 'test 2');
INSERT INTO `media` VALUES ('3', '3 ', 'http://goeshere2.com', '/images/slideshow/tsord.jpg', 'test 3');
```

Any info would be usefull 
Thanks in advance and cheers ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code, I would say that `$data2` represents the data of 1 line from the DB.

So, it should be `$data2` that contains what you want to display.

Your foreach loop is useless : if you want to display the data from 1 line, you can just use `$data2` directly.

If you want to go line by line, you must not iterate over $data2, but loop while mysql_fetch_array returns data.

Something like this, I'd say :

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id,fp_thumb,title FROM media") or die(mysql_error());
while ($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo '<li><a href="media.php?id='.$data2['id'].'"><img src="'.$data2['fp_thumb'].'" alt="'.$data2['title'].'" /></a></li>';
}
```

Also, you might want to escape the data your are outputing, to make sure you don't have any kind of HTML/javascript injection -- at least in the src and title, I'd say ; for that, you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Your echo would, then, probably look like this :

```
echo '<li><a href="media.php?id='
    . $data2['id']
    . '"><img src="'
    . htmlspecialchars($data2['fp_thumb'])
    . '" alt="'
    . htmlspecialchars($data2['title'])
    . '" /></a></li>';
```

*(I considered id is an integer, auto-incremented or something like that, so not much of a risk)*

---

**Edit after seeing the comment on another answer**

With what you first used :

$data2 is an associative array, that looks like this :

```
array
  'id' => int 152
  'title' => string 'this is the title' (length=17)
  'fp_thumb' => string 'http://...../' (length=13)
```

Which means the foreach will loop three times, and $val will be :

```
int 152
string 'this is the title' (length=17)
string 'http://...../' (length=13)
```

*(One value for each iteration)*

ie, $val is not an array is a scalar value.

When you do that :

```
$a = 152;
var_dump($a['id']);
```

you get

```
null
```

When doing

```
$a = 'this is the title';
var_dump($a['id']);
```

you get :

```
string 't' (length=1)
```

ie, you only get the first character when using array-access on a string, with a key that is a string.

Note that array-access on a string, with a numeric key, is used to access one character of the array :

```
$a = 'this is the title';
var_dump($a[3]);
```

gets you :

```
string 's' (length=1)
```

For more informations, see the manual page about string, especially [String access and modification by character](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr), which states :

> Characters within strings may be
>   accessed and modified by specifying
>   the zero-based offset of the desired
>   character after the string using
>   square array brackets, as in $str[42].
>   Think of a string as an array of
>   characters for this purpose.

And :

> Non-integer types are converted to
>   integer.

And converting 'title' to an integer gives 0 ; so, you get the first character of the string.

Hope this helps, and you understood "why" ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! this explains a lot !

Comment: You're welcome :-) (The first time I've had that problem with getting only one character of a string, it seemed strange to me too ^^ But there's a perfectly sane explanation ^^ ) Have fun !

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id,fp_thumb,title FROM media") or die(mysql_error());

while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo '<li><a href="media.php?id='.$data2['id'].'"><img src="'.$data2['fp_thumb'].'" alt="'.$data2['title'].'" /></a></li>';
}
?>
```

This displays all of the records in the table.  Is that what you're trying to do?

The important point here is that mysql_fetch_array only retrieves a single record, and you need to call it multiple times to retrieve multiple records.  It will eventually return FALSE when there are no more records to fetch.

Comment: Then, he should use $data2 to do the echoing, and not $val (not initialized anywhere in your code sample)

Comment: ok i get this , but why for each wont work ? or how ould i have to edit it to work ? ( afcourse im going to use the while loop but , this weird thing wont let me sleep tonight )

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() just returns one row at a time, not the whole query result as a big multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over $results with mysql_fetch_array as it only fetches one result for each call:

```
while ($val = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<li><a href="media.php?id='.$val['id'].'"><img src="'.$val['fp_thumb'].'" alt="'.$val['title'].'" /></a></li>';
}
```

Comment: $data2 will be the variable containing the data from the current line, not $val => here should not use $val to do the echoing, I'd say

Comment: oops. the bad habit of copy-pasting.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same output. Later, found the mistake I did. I have initialized that same variable before as a string. Using a new variable solved the problem.
Help found on: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?259452-Only-outputting-first-character-of-array